# SQLite throws Exception Nevertheless CommandText has no error

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'd like to inquiry some database informations of my application, however, **SQLiteException** teasing me.

Here's the message from the Exception.

> SQL logic error or missing database
>
> near "ORDER": syntax error

I tested the command text at SQLite Browser, **It worked fine**. but in Code, The Exception keeps thrown.

Here's some code that I used.

```
    // Database Requesting Point
    // using(var DB = new SQLiteHandler()) skipped

    var QueryText = string.Format(
        "SELECT seq, title, written_date FROM pblog_board WHERE category={0} ORDER BY seq DESC LIMIT {1}"
        , Target, Requests
        ); // Complete Command Text
    var Reader = DB.ExecuteReader(QueryText, null);
```

... And this is ExecuteReader(string, parameters[]) and Query(string, parameters[])

```
public SQLiteDataReader ExecuteReader(string CommandText, CommandParameter[] Parameters)
{
    var Command = Query(CommandText, Parameters);
    return Command.ExecuteReader();
}

private SQLiteCommand Query(string CommandText, CommandParameter[] Parameters)
{
    SQLiteCommand Command = new SQLiteCommand(_currentConnection);
    Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    Command.CommandText = CommandText;

    if (Parameters != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            Command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(
                    parameterName: Parameters[i].ParameterName,
                    value: Parameters[i].ParameterValue
                ));
        }

    return Command;
}
```

I hope this isn't be a glitch of a SQLite library. I coded wrong, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could the the values of your parameters `Target` and `Requests`. What do you have for the direct DB call that succeeds?

You should parameterize your query instead of using `string.Format(..)` to inject the values. You are opening yourself up to SQL injection by using `string.Format(..)`.

Comment: Alright,  I parameterized my query. I didn't see that there's injection vulnerability :).... And the issue solved. `Target` and `Requests` made issues because they're `null`! Thank you.